# Far Manager. Проблема с темным фоном

Tags: far-manager

В фаре нажал F9 -> colors -> Black and White mode. Все везде поменялось, кроме эдитора. Внизу черная огромная полоса, но область написания кода все равно синяя. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не фар раскрашивает, а плагин Colorer. Он раскрашивает редактор в зависимости от типа файла. Отключить его можно в

Параметры/Параметры плагинов/FarColorer и снять галку "Включить"

Options/Plugin configuration/FarColorer и снять галку "Enabled"